# show different content to users from different sites

Tags: javascript, php, referrer

I would like to show different content to users from different traffics. Say some come to my website through www.google.com, some through yahoo.com, others through amazon.com which shows an ad of our website.

I am aware that $_SERVER[‘HTTP_REFERER’] (in php) and document.referrer (in javascript) seem to solve my problem. But when I tried the code in online php (PHPTester) or javascript (fiddle) test, it returns the url of current site, which is PHPTester and fiddle, rather than the site that links to PHPTester and fiddle.

I'm a little bit confused. Am I missing something? How shall I achieve my goal?

Comment: I would be surprised if an online tester allowed you to use `$_SERVER`. Test with your server.

Comment: Why are you confused?.....Just save the server variable to a cookie or session variable. Now do what you want to do.